# Invalid Signature With OAuth 1.0 API

Tags: api, oauth

I am working with an API that uses OAuth 1.0. There is no documentation on the website for the API other than it uses the standard method. I have followed the guide on the twitter site here https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures.

Everything seems to be good to me, but i keep getting a message telling me i have an invalid signature. I started with a class i found on github and i was getting the signature error. The class was massively complicated, so i wrote my own simple class (using C#). I have a constructor that correctly sets all the values being used here. Im 100% sure there is no missing data, the issue has to be with how the signature/request is being generated, but as far as i can see, everything was setup correctly. The output header looks correct and everything is populated. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
public string GenerateHeaderString(string url, string method)
{
    string auth = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + ConsumerKey + "\",oauth_token=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Token) + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"" + SignatureMethod
        + "\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + Timestamp + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + Nonce + "\",oauth_version=\"" + Version + "\",oauth_signature=\"" + GenerateSignature(url, method) + "\"";
    return auth;            
}

public string GenerateSignature(string url, string method)
{
    string signature = method + "&" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url) + "&" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_consumer_key=" + ConsumerKey
        + "&oauth_nonce=" + Nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=" + SignatureMethod + "&oauth_timestamp="
        + Timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + Token + "&oauth_version=" + Version);
    switch(SignatureMethod)
    {
        case "HMAC-SHA1": 
            string keystring = string.Format("{0}&{1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.ConsumerSecret),HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.TokenSecret));

            var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1
            {
                Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keystring)
            };
            byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signature);
            byte[] hashBytes = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);

            this.Signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes));
        break;
    }
    return this.Signature;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you need to URLEncode the signature before you hash it.  The first two ampersands do not get encoded, but everything else does.  Here is some code that I use.  The only issue that I am having is in cases where the querystring contains spaces in the value.

```
        var signatureType = string.Empty;

        switch (((OAuth1)webRequestDetails.Authentication).SignatureMethod)
        {
            case SignatureMethod.HMACSHA1:
            {
                signatureType = "HMAC-SHA1";
                break;
                }
            case SignatureMethod.HMACSHA256:
                {
                    signatureType = "HMAC-SHA256";
                    break;
                }
            case SignatureMethod.PLAINTEXT:
                {
                    signatureType = "PLAINTEXT";
                    break;
                }
        }

        var baseUrl = webRequestDetails.Url;
        var queryStrings = new List<string>();

        var queryStartIndex = baseUrl.IndexOf("?", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (queryStartIndex != -1)
        {
            queryStrings = baseUrl.Substring(queryStartIndex + 1, baseUrl.Length - queryStartIndex - 1).Split('&').ToList();
            baseUrl = baseUrl.Substring(0, queryStartIndex);
        }

        //string builder will be used to append all the key value pairs
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(httpMethod.Method.ToUpper() + "&");
        stringBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(baseUrl));
        stringBuilder.Append("&");

        //the key value pairs have to be sorted by encoded key
        var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"oauth_version", "1.0"},
            {"oauth_consumer_key", ((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).ConsumerKey},
            {"oauth_nonce", ((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).Nonce},
            {"oauth_signature_method", signatureType},
            {"oauth_timestamp", ((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).TimeStamp},
            {"oauth_token", ((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).Token}
        };

        //merge in the querystrings
        foreach (var queryString in queryStrings)
        {
            var queryStringParts = queryString.Split('=');
            dictionary.Add(queryStringParts[0], queryStringParts[1]);
        }

        foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            //append a = between the key and the value and a & after the value
            stringBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString($"{keyValuePair.Key}={keyValuePair.Value}&"));
        }

        var signatureBaseString = stringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, stringBuilder.Length - 3);

        //generation the signature key the hash will use
        var signatureKey =
            Uri.EscapeDataString(((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).ConsumerSecret) + "&" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(((OAuth1) webRequestDetails.Authentication).TokenSecret);

        var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signatureKey));

        //hash the values
        var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(
            hmacsha1.ComputeHash(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signatureBaseString)));

        return signatureString;
```

Comment: The same kind of problem I am facing and that is weird, because the sandbox runs fine but production I keep getting invalid signature HMAC error ! What can it be?